# stickysession not work fine in apache and two Glassfish Instances

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, cluster, glassfish, cookies

I have two application that run in two Glassfish Instances, i configure my apache to use `sticky session` like so :

```
ProxyPass / balancer://Appcluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

But this not work 100% correct, it change some times the instance when the client goes from App1 to App2.

I check the cookies in my navigator it show me something like this :

[image: cookies of browser]

I found another configuration in `web.xml`, like so :

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

So when i make this path like this every thing work fine, but it create a **new context** every navigation between this two application.

Now i configure my Glassfish and set the App1 like a **Default Web Module**, this work fine and the context is the same, and the sever create a new cookie like this :

[image: cookies of browser]

But when i try to connect with the **NO Default Web Module**, it use two Instances.

Can you please propose the right configuration of Apache and Glassfish to run multiple application in a cluster environment?

**EDIT**

I notified some thing, so when client goes from App1 to App2, and the VS, every time it create a new cookie like this:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------+
| APP   | Cookie                                 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+-----+
| app1  | b5a1cd4befdc306f6e569d835b5e.instance2 | New |              
+-------+----------------------------------------+-----+
| app2  | b6caf890638a506216d625f7c82b.instance2 | New |                                  
+-------+----------------------------------------+-----+
| app1  | b6d1870ad8f3d044cc768b31e810.instance2 | New |                                   
+-------+----------------------------------------+-----+
| app2  | b6d84bf7b2a6fc37e3c9ffaf701b.instance2 | New |
+-------+----------------------------------------+-----+
| app2  | b6d84bf7b2a6fc37e3c9ffaf701b.instance2 |Same | because i don't change the application
+-------+----------------------------------------+-----+
```

- Why this create a new cookie every time?
- How can fix and make it unique per application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one week of search finally i found the solution :

I use two things, one in the two applications and one in the server Apache :

So in the applicatons we should to define the name of the cookie in **web.xml**:

**APP1**

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>

    <cookie-config>
        <name>jsessionapp1</name>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

**APP2**

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>

    <cookie-config>
        <name>jsessionapp2</name>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

And in the server Apache we fix the name of **stickysession** in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd_proxy.conf** :

```
ProxyPass / balancer://Appcluster/ stickysession=jsessionapp1|jsessionapp2|jsessionappN
```

I don't know if there another solutions better than this, if yes i will be happy to know them.